# Would this be a legal VHDL architecture?

Tags: vhdl

I want to design a basic BCD to XS3 converter using VHDL. I am fairly new to
conditional and behavioral architecture implementation, but I was wondering if this would be a legal program, especially my assign statements

```
entity bcd2xs3 is
    port (bcd : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
          xs3 : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));
end bcd2xs3;

architecture behav of bcd2xs3 is
    begin
    case bcd is
        when X"0"|X"1"|X"2"|X"3"|X"4"|X"5"|X"6"|X"7"|X"8"|X"9" => xs3 <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(integer(unsigned(bcd))+3));
        when others => xs3 <= X"0";
    end case;
end behav;
```

Comment: No, it's not a legal program. You don't have a context clause (e.g. `library ieee; use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; use ieee.numeric_std.all;`preceding the entity declaration) making type declarations for  std_logic_vector  and unsigned visible. Also a a case statement is sequential statement belonging in this case in a process statement (sensitive to bcd). Your choice should be `when X"0"|X"1"|X"2"|X"3"|X"4"|X"5"|X"6"|X"7"|X"8"|X"9" => xs3 <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(bcd) + 3);` (no integer type conversion, which isn't allowed or necessary here anyway).

Comment: As an alternative to putting the case statement in a process, there are "conditional assignment" and "selected signal assignment" statements you can use in the concurrent statement region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer this solution

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity bcd2xs3 is
  port (bcd : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        xs3 : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));
end bcd2xs3;

architecture behav of bcd2xs3 is
  signal bcd_int: integer;

begin
  bcd_int <= to_integer(unsigned(bcd));

  process (bcd_int )
    begin 
      case bcd_int is
        when 0 to 9 => 
          xs3 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(bcd_int + 3), bcd'length);
        when others => 
          xs3 <= X"0";
      end case;
  end process;
end architecture behav;
```

Comment: Ahh, I see, we could do that and do a 0 to 9 condition so we do not have to do a bunch of |